# Group array base on maximum and length

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, lodash

Having a hard time to group this array. any suggestions.

As an example I have an array `var a = [10, 100, 20, 50, 20, 50, 70, 120]`

and I have a maximum of `150` and minimum length of `3` i.e each sub array can have a total maximum sum of 150 and a maximum length of 3

any suggestion to make it like this `[[10, 100, 20], [50, 20, 50], [70], [120]]`

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, the groupArray function will iterate on your input and build groups based on max length and max sum provided.

```js
function groupArray(input, maxSum, maxLen) {
  const res = [[]];
  let mark = 0;
  let sum = 0;

  input.forEach( ele => {  
    // if the current group has already reach maxLenght or maxSum
    // then create a new group
    if ( res[mark].length > (maxLen-1)
        || (sum + ele) > maxSum ) {
      res.push([ele]);
      mark++;
      sum = ele;
    }
    // otherwise add to current grop
    else {
      res[mark].push(ele);
      sum += ele;
    }
  });
  return res;
}

const test_1 = [10, 100, 20, 50, 20, 50, 70, 120];
const test_2 = [10, 130, 20, 50, 20, 50, 70, 120];
const test_3 = [140, 110, 20, 50, 20, 50, 70, 120];

console.log(groupArray(test_1, 150, 3));
console.log(groupArray(test_2, 150, 3));
console.log(groupArray(test_3, 150, 3));
```

Note: Since the question did not have any additional rules, this function does not reorder the array or try to look for the best possible length match or best possible sum matches.